Cloud (Run) Function fails to start on Cloud Run - Container failed to start and listen on PORT=8080 after Recent Change
I'm deploying a Python Google Cloud Function (Gen2)(Recently renamed into Cloud Run Function), thats works perfectly in same structure and logic before the changes , but right now just not working.
And i tested the server runs perfectly locally 8080. but fails when try to deploy to the cloud Run. The function is a simple HTTP endpoint that act as an webhook:
it trigger when my services calling this endpoint , and my webhook will do some firebase stuff and return the json responds.
Locally:
functions-framework --source main.py --target hi_kata --debug
 * Serving Flask app 'hi_kata'
 * Debug mode: on
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Running on all addresses (0.0.0.0)
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:8080
 * Running on http://10.241.125.3:8080

Keep getting this Error and nothing else...

message=Could not create or update Cloud Run service Kata-v3, Container Healthcheck failed. Revision '  ' is not ready and cannot serve traffic. The user-provided container failed to start and listen on the p failed. Revision '  ' is not ready and cannot serve traffic. The user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port defined provided by the PORT=8080 environment variable within the allocated timeout. This can happen when the container port is misconfigured or if the timeout is too short. The health check timeout can be extended. Logs for this revision might contain more information.

And saw this in the Cloud run services :

Traceback (most recent call last):
. ( /layers/google.python.pip/pip/bin/functions-framework:8 )

Edit 1 (My Log):
ERROR 2024-12-30T09:56:20.897531Z Traceback (most recent call last): File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/bin/functions-framework", line 8, in <module> sys.exit(_cli())
DEFAULT 2024-12-30T09:56:20.897557Z ^^^^^^
DEFAULT 2024-12-30T09:56:20.897564Z File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.11/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1161, in __call__
DEFAULT 2024-12-30T09:56:20.899632Z return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
DEFAULT 2024-12-30T09:56:20.899843Z ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
DEFAULT 2024-12-30T09:56:20.899851Z File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.11/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1082, in main
DEFAULT 2024-12-30T09:56:20.900173Z rv = self.invoke(ctx)
DEFAULT 2024-12-30T09:56:20.900338Z ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
DEFAULT 2024-12-30T09:56:20.900348Z File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.11/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1443, in invoke
DEFAULT 2024-12-30T09:56:20.900681Z return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
DEFAULT 2024-12-30T09:56:20.900945Z ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
DEFAULT 2024-12-30T09:56:20.900954Z File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.11/site-packages/click/core.py", line 788, in invoke
DEFAULT 2024-12-30T09:56:20.901182Z return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
DEFAULT 2024-12-30T09:56:20.901376Z ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
DEFAULT 2024-12-30T09:56:20.901384Z File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.11/site-packages/functions_framework/_cli.py", line 36, in _cli
DEFAULT 2024-12-30T09:56:20.906593Z app = create_app(target, source, signature_type)
DEFAULT 2024-12-30T09:56:20.906846Z ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
DEFAULT 2024-12-30T09:56:20.906857Z File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.11/site-packages/functions_framework/__init__.py", line 395, in create_app
DEFAULT 2024-12-30T09:56:20.907858Z raise e from None
DEFAULT 2024-12-30T09:56:20.907902Z File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.11/site-packages/functions_framework/__init__.py", line 376, in create_app
DEFAULT 2024-12-30T09:56:20.908084Z spec.loader.exec_module(source_module)
DEFAULT 2024-12-30T09:56:20.908117Z File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
DEFAULT 2024-12-30T09:56:20.908121Z File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
DEFAULT 2024-12-30T09:56:20.908138Z File "/workspace/main.py", line 15, in <module>


Here's My Structure in short:
import os
import json
from flask import Flask, jsonify
import functions_framework
from google.oauth2 import id_token
from google.auth.transport import requests

import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials, firestore, db
from openai import AzureOpenAI



firebase_admin.initialize_app()
db_fs = firestore.client()



def some_function():
    pass


def some_function1():
    pass

@functions_framework.http
def hi_kata(request):
    
    try:
        auth_header = request.headers.get('Authorization')
        if not auth_header:
            print("Missing Authorization header")
            return 'Unauthorized - Missing token', 401

        id_token_str = auth_header.split(' ')[1]
        # My auth Logic here
        audience = " "

        # Auth token
        try:
            id_info = id_token.verify_oauth2_token(
                id_token_str, 
                requests.Request(), 
                audience
            )
            print(f"Token verified for user: {id_info.get('email', 'unknown')}")
            
        except ValueError as e:
            print(f"Token verification failed: {str(e)}")
            return 'Unauthorized - Invalid token', 401

        # Steps 2.
        
        request_json = request.get_json(silent=True)
        if not request_json:
            return 'No request data provided', 400
        
        
        try:
            # ....
                        
            return jsonify(response_to_my_function), 200

        except KeyError as e:
            print(f"Missing required field: {str(e)}")
            return f'Invalid request format: missing {str(e)}', 400

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Unexpected error: {str(e)}")
        return 'Internal server error', 500

my Requirement.txt  (Python version 3.11)
functions-framework==3.8.2
google-cloud-secret-manager==2.16.3
Flask==2.2.5
google-auth
google-auth-httplib2
firebase-admin ==6.5.0
google-cloud-firestore==2.16.0


It seems like theres an exception thrown? What is that Traceback, I assume the line that throws the exception in your code is in there.

@somethingsomething  added my log^*,not sure whats that is

The error that you get "container failed to start and listen on the port defined provided by the PORT=8080" is a generic error to say that you container did not start (i.e. it crashed at startup). What did you change since your previous working version?
